# Ответ раньше времени в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема: есть скрипт, который по нажатию кнопки отправляет ajax на сервер на Django с некоторыми данными. Сервер собирает некую информацию в список, что занимает время (секунд 10), и должен возвращать клиенту длину этого списка.

```
def f(request):
    . . .
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'count': len(some_list)}))
```

В итоге приходит значение 0, а должно приходить около 500. И промежуток времени между запросом и ответом минимальный. При подсчете длины в терминале выводит все верно.
Если я, допустим, решу вывести длину простого списка, то ответ приходит, как и должен:

```
def f(request):
    . . .
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'count': len([1, 2, 3])})) # {'count': 3}
```

Пробовал писать setTimeout(), но это никак не помогает. Внимание, вопрос: что же делать, если, по видимому, ответа ajax ждет немного?

Comment: Покажите js-код. Подозреваю, что нужно установить таймаут и обработчик таймаута.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/91go0dg5/1/
Таймаут в ajax-запросе, кстати, пробовал делать: эффекта ноль.

Comment: Ajax ждет ответа до конца или вываливает ошибку таймаута, никаких выдуманных данных он не вернет просто так. Значит в вашем случае просто ответ приходит неправильный. Пробуйте ввести логирование на стороне сервера и проверить значения во время реального запроса.

Comment: Что происходит, если серверный код заменить на `time.sleep(10); some_list=[1]*5`? В таких случаях лучше клиент и сервер независимо отлаживать, то есть использовать заглушки, например для отладки сервера можно руками фиксированный http запрос делать любыми привычными средствами (curl, httpie, etc).

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь интерфейсом Promises в вашем JS коде
например,так:

```js
loadData = function() {
  var promise = $.Deferred();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/some/url/',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      // some manipulations with response if needed
      promise.resolve(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      // some manipulations with response if needed
      promise.reject(response)
    }
  });

  return promise
};

$(function() {
  $('#loadDataBtn').on('click', function() {
    loadData()
      .done(someFunctionForDataDisplaying)
  })
})
```

в таком случае сперва выполнится функция, получающая данные (loadData), а затем запустится функция, работающая с полученными данными (callback done()).

Но, конечно, лучше бы увидеть Ваш JS код.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/91go0dg5/1/
Я вот чего не понял, функция, которая работает с полученными данными, откуда она их берет? Каким образом к ним обращаться?

Comment: @6082asil существует механизм chaining для Deferred объектов - в callback передается результат разрешения Deferred объекта; таким образом `someFunctionForDataDisplaying` получит результат работы функции `loadData` из Promise в случае вызова `promise.resolve(response)`. При этом в done для функции `someFunctionForDataDisplaying` можно не писать скобки и аргумент. Давайте перепишем callback так, если будет понятнее, `.done(function(response){})`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xnsuhvt/
Я сделал так, но что-то сомневаюсь, что правильно. Теперь при отправке формы не происходит ничего.

Comment: @6082asil а зачем вам timeout в 20000? В dev tools при сабмите формы запрос отправляется на сервер?

Comment: @6082asil поправил немного фиддл - не нужен `var` перед объявлением функции `req`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5xnsuhvt/1/
Отредактировал немного код, работает, но снова возвращает 0.

Comment: @6082asil в JS пока больше ничего плохого не вижу. А что на сервере при этом делается, можете показать?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9656dxtw/
Все, что угодно, лишь бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы заработало.
В коде функции парсят ссылки с сайта.